# Soundcloud Flash Widget, trying to play next song on page

Tags: java, javascript, soundcloud

I'm creating a personal blog with my friend where we are uploading our favorite songs via soundcloud and want songs to play one after another.

This is the general idea of what each song will be listed on the page. http://jsfiddle.net/PJWQZ/

```
<div class="item">
<object height="200" width="200"> <param name="movie" value=        "https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F60974071&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork&amp;color=0066cc"> 
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"> <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="200" width="200" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F60974071&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork&amp;color=0066cc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">          </object> 
</div>
```

Only problem is that once a song finishes nothing happens. And I was looking to see if it is possible to use Javascript to find when the song ends (using onMediaEnd) and automatically play the next song in line, without having to use the playlist API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on the [Custom Player API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player).

http://jsfiddle.net/8mWXq/

I couldn't get the graphics to load on JSFiddle but click the first track to start it playing, then FF (click) near the end and when the first track stops the second will start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SC player example: Artwork Skin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sc-player-artwork.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>I Love Cover-Art</h1>
    <div class="post">  
      <h2>2012</h2>
      <div class="sc-player">
        <a href="http://soundcloud.com/kreek/you-know-it" class="sc-player">Track 1</a>
        <a href="http://soundcloud.com/kreek/amnesia" class="sc-player">Track 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/soundcloud.player.api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/sc-player.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```